# Django vs Grails vs Lift for Comet support?

Tags: python, django, grails, comet

I am going to be developing a real-time web application that will make heavy use of Ajax and Comet programming techniques. I am wondering which web framework will be best to use for this type of application.

I already know Python and Django, I have built a smaller app in Grails, and have experience with Scala but not Lift. Based on this, can anyone advise me on which framework to use and what plugins (if any) are required for Comet integration?

Comment: *"I am going to be developing a real-time web application"* - good luck with that! How are you planning to get around the internet latency?

Comment: @mac I mean, an app that uses comet techniques to allow the server to push rather than polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also consider [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) in the list of web frameworks. Together with [tornad.io](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio), a tornado version of socket.io javascript lib, it makes Comet techniques easy.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if you consider to go with  grails , there are some plugins which might help

- [Atmosphere](http://www.grails.org/plugin/atmosphere)
- [Cometd](http://www.grails.org/plugin/cometd)
- [Pusher](http://www.grails.org/plugin/pusher)